# Replacing the content of an element by the value of an arbitrary attribute with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to replace the content of an element by the value of an arbitrary attribute, if the elemnt has this attribute. I need to do that with an XSLT sheet (2.0), but I have no idea how I could do such a thing.

For example, let's say I have this xml document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document> 
  Hi my name is <tag-A flag="Bob">Leopold</tag-A>
  and I'm fond of <tag-B flag="coding">literature</tag-B>
  unless in the <tag-C whatever="evening">morning</tag-C>
</document>
```

Then the xslt would change the content of any element that has a `flag` attribute, let's say, for the value of that attribute and put everything enclosed in a `<p>` tag. This is the output I would get in that case.

```
<p>Hi my name is Bob
and I'm fond of coding
unless in the morning</p>
```

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: Your example does not "replace the content of a tag" - it replaces the entire element with the value of the given attribute. In any case, this seems like a pretty basic XSLT task; what exactly is your difficulty with it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant element. -edited- Yeah I know it might be basic xslt, but still, I started learning xslt yesterday and have no idea how to pull this off. <xsl:value-of select="@flag"> gets all the values of the flag attributes, ok for that, but then? I dont even know where to start honestly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces the output you've been asking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match = "document">
  <p><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "*[@flag]">
  <xsl:value-of select="@flag"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that @whatever is happily ignored, but could be folded in easily.

Also, I don't think that you'll be happy with a doc with <p> as its outermost element?

Comment: ahhhh now I get it, I didn't understand quite well how to use templates. And the <p> element was just for the example :P. It's quite a complex thing I'm working on actually. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Except the third attribute in the example is "whatever" and not "flag" ... was the intention to replace any attribute or only the "flag" attributes?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: It is unclear what you mean as the question title says "arbitrary" and then the text in the question says "flag" attribute. IF your XML is only as show and you want to replace with *any* attribute and you have only one, you could do it this way (XSL 1.0 is all that is required):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="document">
       <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output from your XML is:

```
<p> 
Hi my name is Bob
and I'm fond of coding
unless in the evening
</p>
```

Comment: If the post ws only to replace "flag" attribute, this would not work. It was unclear whether only "flag" or any attribute was the requirement.

Comment: If you replace `node()` with `element()` you can even omit the last template. - I wasn't so sure about the name of the attribute, either.